# Working with an Unordered List to calculate team stats

Tags: java, list

I'm working on a Sports program in which I have an Unordered List which contains multiple Player objects. These player objects are players for a basketball team and have attributes for Team(string), Total points scored(int), etc.

I am currently trying to write a method that will calculate the highest scoring team in the league. So my list has multiple player objects each with their individual total points scored and I'm trying to use this to figure out the team that has scored the most points.

I can easily calculate the player with the most points by looping through the list and finding the highest point value and then looping again to find players who have scored = to the highest value found in the previous loop. The problem is I don't know how to do this with the whole team, especially since all point values now must belong to a team.

Thanks

Comment: You could create a `TeamStats` class.  `TeamStats` can just keep references to every player that is a member of that team.  Then for `TeamStats teamA`, you can `teamA.getTeamPointsScore()` and it will iterate through the players on the team, sum up their scores, and return that value.  Then you can sort teams, based on `getTeamPointsScore()` the same way you'd sort players based on `playerA.getPlayerPointsScored()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Map, you can do something like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> teamsPoints = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (Player player : players)
{
    Integer teamPoints = teamsPoints.get(player.getTeamName());
    if (teamPoints == null)
        teamsPoints.put(player.getTeamName(), player.getPoints());
    else
        teamsPoints.put(player.getTeamName(), teamPoints + player.getPoints());
}
```

You can iterate over the map like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> teamPoints: teamsPoints.entrySet()) 
{
    System.out.println("Team = " + teamPoints.getKey() + ", Total points= " + teamPoints.getValue());
}
```